# What's CPD of the Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, cpd

I works with Sonarqube every day in my job. But, I realized that I don't know what means CPD. Phrases like "INFO: CPD calculation finished", etc. I would like some help to know this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Copy/Paste Detection?

[Wikipedia: Copy/Paste Detector (CPD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_(software)#Copy/Paste_Detector_(CPD))

From [Sonarqube docs: Analysis Parameters, Duplication](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/analysis-parameters/#duplications):

> A piece of code is considered duplicated as soon as there are at least 100 duplicated tokens in a row (override with `sonar.cpd.${language}.minimumTokens`) spread across at least 10 lines of code